# Svn command line

Tags: svn

I just Installed the latest version of tortoise svn with command line included in it. So I need to use command line but when I try to run, it closes automatically and the same with sliksvn I tried to install. How can I solve it?

Comment: [Launch a command prompt](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8) first, _then_ use SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to open a command prompt to run. Svn needs parameters, without it starts and closes.

On Windows: start and type cmd, navigate to the executable and run. 
On Linux use the terminal.

Don't forget to read the book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/